# Difference between WSDualHttpBinding and NetHttpBinding

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I am writing a set of WCF services that will communicate with each other. I want to be able to establish a two-way connection between the servers. However, at some point, different types of clients (.NET or Javascript) should be able to communicate with these services.

I am currently using callbacks in WsDualHttpBinding, and it seems to do the trick, at least in a basic sense. Services can send basic messages to each other. My concern is opening multiple connections, as bandwidth might become a problem in the future.

I am fearful that NetHttpBinding is a much better tool to use. 
I want to know what are some advantages or disadvantages of using NetHttpBinding compared to WSDualHttpBinding.

Answer (score 1):

WSDualHttpBinding has a wider reach since it supports HTTP protocol.
NetHttpBinding  however is faster by some margin since it works on nettcp in a network.

Comment: Doesn't NetHttpBinding also support HTTP protocol when WS not available?

Answer (score 0):

**WSDualHttpBinding** was created for a reason. WCF provided support for service 'callbacks' - methods on the client that were notified whenever service execution completed. Unfortunately, HTTP - being a one way channel - would not allow for callbacks (by contrast, the TCPBinding allows it since TCP is a full duplex channel). To get around HTTP's one-way nature, the DualHttpBinding was invented - two simultaneously open HTTP connections - one for the service request - and one for the callback.

**NetHttpBinding** is a binding designed for consuming HTTP or WebSocket services and uses binary encoding by default. NetHttpBinding will detect whether it is used with a request-reply contract or duplex contract and change its behavior to match - it will use HTTP for request-reply and WebSockets for duplex.